# How to specify URLs from glassware .net application

Tags: google-mirror-api

I would like specify Urls as in the below code in my .net glassware application

```
{
IList<string> imageUrls = new List<string>();
imageUrls.Add (what is it here?")
Iconact.ImageUrls = imageUrls;
}
```

Currently this url will be used at the time of rendering at the device (or mirror api?), so web app, this url makes sense, how about .net client as a glassware, i have my image as part of the glassware app and how to pass this image as a url?

Similar question how to specify subscription endpoint url in .net app?, it makes sense in web app, but i could not get the concept in .net client.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those assets need to be hosted somewhere: they don't necessarily need to be within your Glassware and can be hosted separately. However, those URLs need to be publicly accessible for the Glass client to fetch them.

You could host them on a free Google App Engine app that only purpose would be to serve those images.

Regarding the subscription endpoint: it needs to be publicly accessible and support `POST` requests over HTTPS.

Comment: Url for the asset makes sense, i could have Google App Engine app or using my google drive folder, right?.  Is it possible to have a .net client as a subscription endpoint?

Comment: Subscription endpoint needs to be publicly accessible so running a local .NET app won't work. You can work around this by doing some sort of proxy by having a hosted web app stores the notification for you and polling from your client.

Comment: When timelineitem is shared to my glassware it shows it is shared, but i don't get notification (it could be because of notification end-point), how about simply polling and getting timelineitem, is there a way to traverse and find out correct timeline item.

Comment: You can poll with the [mirror.timeline.list](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/list) endpoint but you will need to know which item you've inserted and which one were shared with you by checking the `recipients` property.

Comment: Yes, that's how i'm doing, by storing date and time of last processed shared item, i could figure out recently shared items. If i'm able to get notification working by adding WCF or webservices to my .net app would be great. (or) i need to have a app(google app engine) portion for that.

Comment: How about creating WebServiceHost and adding service end point, will it work? such as that :WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost( typeof(Service), new Uri("https://localhost:8000/"));

Comment: The subscription endpoint needs to be publicly accessible since the push notifications will be sent from Google's servers; they won't be able to reach your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be that creating WebServiceHost and adding service end point such as:

```
 WebServiceHost host = new WebServiceHost(typeof(Service), new Uri("http://localhost:8000/"));
ServiceEndpoint ep = host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService), new WebHttpBinding(), "");
host.Open();
```

Will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Finally what I did was that as in the Alain's answer having a Java Servlet app running in Google App Engine which receives all the notification and maintains all the user account logic and sends the notification to specific client(part of glassware app) in the local system thru XML over XMPP.